# secure login Android / PHP

Tags: php, android, security, authentication

I use (sever side) a mysql db with php and (client side) Android. 
I would like to control data access.
How I can make a SECURE login using Android and php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most applications these days use OAuth to handle this: Facebook, twitter, etc..  The idea is based on logging in, and then keeping a token to make requests to the API at the other end.  While OAuth is not extremely simple, there are libraries out there for Android and PHP, and it's a trusted authentication strategy. You can Google for finding out how to implement OAuth in PHP, and there are libraries to handle OAuth on Android (really just Java, with APIs that are available on Android):  http://oauth.net/code/

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure on this but maybe you could send the login data to the server (Like $_POST data), and return a token (Like $_SESSION data) to be used for the rest of the user transactions.

Comment: And don't forget to do it over SSL (HTTPS). This is exactly how most basic authentication systems do it.

Comment: Adding to this, for a more advanced security system, you could encrypt your data on either side with the token, but that is basically what SSL does.